# Azure Web Job logs can keep up to maximum 51 items?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am working with Azure webjobs and I want to check my webjob log information, however I notice that it only can keep up to maximum 51 items for each web job as shown below:

[image: Logs from Kudu]

[image: Logs from WebJobs Logs]

Please advise is there any way to increase the number of the log items?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of now WEBJOBS_HISTORY_SIZE default size is limited to 50 as per WebJob [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings). You can change WEBJOBS_HISTORY_SIZE value in Application setting.

You can refer to [What is the limit of Azure webjob logs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/436697/what-is-the-limit-of-azure-webjob-logs.html)